# The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file: - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, compiler-optimization, rewire

I just cloned a react/typescript template repository and did `npm install` I should say that the node packages installed in this app is really large number and react rewired is installed too, also the required `node version is 12.10.0`
I came in to a problem when I run `npm start` the terminal shows this message
`The following changes are being made to your tsconfig.json file:   - compilerOptions.paths must not be set (aliased imports are not supported)`
and it keep hanging on `Starting the development server...` 
I should say it takes ages.

- I switched port number and specified the mount of resources to use in `package.json`  "start": "PORT=3001 react-app-rewired --max_old_space_size=8128 start",` but no satisfy result accrued
- I removed `node_modules` and reinstall again but it didn't help

[image]`